# Allow Blender Matierals to Reflect Ambient Light Color

Tags: light

I'm trying to light a scene in blender. I have set the diffuse color but want it to reflect ambient light as well. When I turn up the ambient light reflection and turn up the scene ambient light, the object reflects the ambient light but reflects white light instead of the green light I want it to. Its produces a washed out effect. How do you light it so the dark part of the sphere reflects a little green from the ambient light and the bright spot reflects the green from both the ambient light and the diffuse light.

Comment: Often times using ambient light will produce a washed out effect.  You may want to consider using the world color instead of the ambient.

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: I'm using cycles right now. I am using it to create a learning database for some inverse rendering machine learning algorithm according to the Phong reflection model and am trying to light the same scene with ambient light, ambient & diffuse, and ambient & diffuse & specular